# MySQL 'addInstance' fix

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, replicaset

I am trying to add another configured MySQL database as replica of my master database. I've followed all the instructions, and till now everything is ok.

The replica I try to add, is on another ip adress as the master. So I tried the following, to add the secondary database to the master: rs.addInstance('dbrep@myip000:3306') where 'dbrep' is the username, and myip000 is of course replaced by the ip of the other MySQL database.

This is the error I get: **ReplicaSet.addInstance: Invalid URI: Octet value out of bounds [950], valid range for IPv4 is 0 to 255 at position 9 (ArgumentError)**

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may have a problem with the value in _myip000_

Comment: Hmm, but it's a valid IP address, so that's weird...

Comment: Can you publish the IP???

Comment: Maybe in private? Is it possible?

Comment: But I don't Know how to do it

Comment: Okay, I've changed some numbers to another value. But the setup of the IP is the same. Just to be more safe, because it's my public ip. 

This is the command: rs.addInstance('dbrep@56.942.125.221:3306')

And this IP, is the public IP of the other MySQL instance, which I want to add as slave

Comment: Ok, you must know than a Public IP is formed by 4 groups of values that must go from 0 to 255. I can see that you have a 942 ( i don't know if in the real IP appears like that)

Comment: Yes, it is in the real IP. That's weird!

Comment: The IP can't have any value over 255, so that IP is wrong, and that corresponds with the error you are getting _Invalid URI: Octet value out of bounds [950], valid range for IPv4 is 0 to 255 at position 9_

Comment: I think i've made a mistake indeed...

Comment: Now I've got this error: ERROR: The administrative account credentials for 51.1xx.1x9.x04:3306 do not match the cluster's administrative account. The cluster administrative account user name and password must be the same on all instances that belong to it.
ReplicaSet.addInstance: Could not open connection to '51.1xx.1x9.x04:3306': Access denied for user 'root'@'vps-480ce.vps.ovh.net' (using password: YES) (MySQL Error 1045)

Comment: Ok, you need to have the same user/password in both systems (master & replica) (Try not to use root user)

Comment: You mean mysql, or the whole system?

Comment: Just for MySql, you can follow this tutorial to make the replica **https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql**

Comment: Thanks mate! Have a great day